# Is it possible to trigger Sagemaker notebook from AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to trigger Sagemaker notebook or Sagemaker Studio notebook from AWS Lambda when data is available in S3 bucket. I want to know if this is possible and if yes, how?

All I want is once data is uploaded in S3, the lambda function should be able to spin up the Sagemaker notebook with a standard CPU cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Jupyter plug in that you can use to do this, please note this is not managed by AWS. It is experimental software and should be used that way.

https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-run-notebook

Using this extension, you can run your notebook based on an event.

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.